# php foreach create html table autometic generate tr tag?

Tags: php, html

hello friends i want to display two td tag in one tr.
this is is write into foreach loop.

this is my code.

```
$rri=0;
foreach ($related as $key => $value) {
    if($rri % 2 == 0 ){
          echo "<tr class='dsfdsf'>";
          echo "<td >".$rri."</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
    }else{
          echo "<td >".$rri."</td>";
    }

     $rri++;
}
```

this is my php code it return out put is under

```
<table>
<tr class='dsfdsf'>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr class='dsfdsf'>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr class='dsfdsf'>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
 </table>
```

i want to output like this

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

foreachloop add new tr tag.

i checked odd  or even this is working but unfortunate tr is added.

please help,

Thank you.

Comment: Why not using simple for loop instead of foreach? U need iterator anyway, so it'd be better i guess. Also, try %2 == 1 if u iterate from 0. Because 0 % 0 = 0. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the `</tr>` oudside the `if` and set it in `else` statement.

```
echo '<table>';
$rri=0;
foreach ($related as $key => $value) {        
    if($rri % 2 == 0 ){
        echo '<tr class="dsfdsf">';
        echo '<td>'.$rri.'</td>';

    }else{
        echo '<td>'.$rri.'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    $rri++;
}
echo'</table>';
```

Comment: This results in invalid HTML

Comment: Why? @Florent but that isnt the case right now. is it? what kind of invalid result PeeHaa ??

Comment: I do not see `$related`. `$key` or `$value begin used anywhere inside the loop, so why not use a straight `for` loop and increment by `++2`?

Comment: @DevlshOne because renishkhunt is only asking how to fix it.. maybe she/he uses the foreach in there real code but not in this sample to make it easier to explain..... So it is  irrelevant to make it in a loop...

Comment: @PeeHaa why does it result in invalid html?

Comment: Have you tried it? Try to get OPs output with the above and look at the source.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this will help find your solution in a different but effective way:

```
<?php
    $related = array(1,2,3,4,5);
    $chunk   = 2;
?>

<table>
    <?php foreach (array_chunk($related, $chunk) as $row): ?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($row as $val): ?>
        <td><?php echo $val; ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$rri=0;
foreach ($related as $key => $value) {
    if($rri % 2 == 0 ){
        if($rri  > 0){
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "<tr class='dsfdsf'>";
     }

     echo "<td>".$rri."</td>";

     $rri++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
$rri=1;
echo "<tr class='dsfdsf'>";
foreach ($related as $key => $value) {

    echo "<td >".$rri."</td>";
    if($rri % 2 == 0 ){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }
    $rri++;
}
echo "</tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$related=array('1','2','3','4');
$rri=0;
 echo "<table border=1 width=500>";
foreach ($related as $key => $value) {
    if($rri % 2 == 0 || $rri==0 ){
          echo "<tr class='dsfdsf'>";
        }
     echo "<td >".$rri."</td>";
      if($rri/2 == 0 && $rri!=0 ){
       echo "</tr>"  ; 
       }

     $rri++;
} echo "</table>";?>
```

Try This

Answer (score -1):

```
for ($i = 0; $i <= $rri; $i+=2) {
    echo "<tr class='dsfdsf'>\n";
    echo "<td>$i</td>\n";
    echo "<td>$i+1</td?\n";
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
```

Comment: If you really wanted to get fancy, just echo a list of all the `<td>`s and then use `.wrapAll` around every two.